# unable to select image corners in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to select the image corner's and crop it and then perform perspective transform on it.

but when I run this code, the window with an image opens up, but on double click, nothing happens so that I with double click, I could select image corners.

here's my code

```
from transform import four_point_transform
import imutils
from skimage.filters import threshold_adaptive
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("test1.jpg")
ratio = image.shape[0] / 500.0
orig = image.copy()


window_name = "Select corner points of object"
cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow(window_name, image)

pts_1 = []

def callback(event, x, y, flags, param):
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
                pts_1.append((x, y))
                cv2.circle(image,(x,y),10,(0,255,0),5)
                cv2.imshow(window_name, image)
                if(len(pts_1)==4):
                        pts = np.array(pts_1,dtype="float32")
                        print(pts_1)
                        warped = four_point_transform(orig, pts)
                        warped = cv2.cvtColor(warped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                        warped = threshold_adaptive(warped, 251, offset = 10)
                        warped = warped.astype("uint8") * 255
                        cv2.imshow("Original", imutils.resize(orig, height = 650))
                        cv2.imshow("Scanned", imutils.resize(warped, height = 650))
                        cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.setMouseCallback(window_name, callback)
key = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Have you tried calling `cv2.imshow` after `cv2.setMouseCallback`?

Comment: yes, still not working

Comment: @HåkenLid: I think the problem is with the platform, because when i try same snippet on ubuntu it works, while on Mac it doesn't

Comment: I have no idea. I think opencv uses QT for GUI-functionality like this. Seems to be some platform specific differences, unfortunately.